# Desktop not coming up & black screen after updates

Tags: updates, boot, display

I installed updates and after the restart, the screen comes up black with a blinking cursor. I can get to terminal by ctrl-alt-F1 and sign in, but all attempts to troubleshoot have failed. This is disturbing as this is my development environment and I will lose some progress if I do a fresh install. I am running this in a VirtualBox on a Windows 10 computer. It is a Sony VAIO with 12G RAM, Intel Core i7 2Ghz processor. I have run updates and upgrade through the terminal, then rebooted a few times, but this is not working either. Please help!

Comment: Same issue. Running in VirtualBox on Windows 7. Tried using boot recovery options such as fsck and dpkg but no joy. Attempted updates on a much older instance of the same OS (cloned some time ago) and got the same problem after updating all software using apt-get update and upgrade. Booting from older kernel version does not resolve the problem. Possible graphical interface problem? I.e. lightdm or gpu-management services.

Comment: Cracked it. Please see my answer in: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/15197/cant-start-gui-in-elementary-os-loki-0-4-1/15669#15669